# Как объеденить два SQL запроса для разных таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `users` пользователей

```
+--+----+-----+
+id+name+email+
+--+----+-----+
+ 1+ivan+a@com+
+ 2+vasa+a@com+
+ 3+peta+a@com+
...
```

И таблица `posts` публикаций

```
+--+---------+
+id+author_id+
+--+---------+
+ 1+        1+
+ 2+        1+
+ 3+        2+
...
```

Проще говоря, не все пользователи являются авторами.
Вот так я могу выбрать только авторов:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `author_id` FROM `posts`
```

Как получить данные по всем полям для пользователей, которые являются авторами (как-то объеденить вышеупомянутый запрос и `SELECT * FROM users`)?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT \`author_id\` FROM \`posts\`)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо!

Comment: select * from users u where exists (select 1 from posts p where u.id = p.author_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте `JOIN` одной таблицы к другой:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.email
FROM users u
JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.author_id
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш вариант!

Comment: мне подошел вариант Алексея, но он в формате комментария. Не могу отметить как решение)

Comment: @Tarasovych на больших таблицах `join`, в отличие от подзапроса, будет отрабатывать, по идее, быстрее.